# Why is my looping GUI timer not showing up?

Tags: java, swing, thread-sleep

I'm trying to make a GUI timer *without using* `javax.swing.Timer`(kind of a strange task), but I am having trouble making it work. It's supposed to sleep the thread for 1 second, add 1 to `seconds`, and repeat(infinitely). When I run my program, the icon shows up, but the window does not appear. I'm guessing my error is in the `Thread.sleep(1000);` line or in that area, but I'm not sure why it doesn't work. Is `Thread.sleep(millis)`not compatible with swing applications? Do I have to multithread? Here's my program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUITimer extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int seconds = 0;

    public GUITimer() {
        initGUI();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void initGUI(){
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Timer");
        Font titleFont = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 32);
        title.setFont(titleFont);
        title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        title.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        title.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        title.setOpaque(true);
        add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JLabel timeDisplay = new JLabel(Integer.toString(seconds));//this label shows seconds
        add(timeDisplay, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        seconds++;
        initGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String className = UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName();
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(className);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GUITimer();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I noticed when I print `seconds` in my method `initGUI()` to console, it prints them incrementally by one second correctly. So when it looks like:

```
private void initGUI() {
    System.out.println(seconds);
    //...
```

it prints the value of `seconds` after every second(How the `JLabel` should). This shows that my loop is working fine, and my `Thread.sleep(1000)` is OK also. My only problem now, is that the frame is not showing up.

Comment: You should start by having a look at [Concurrency In Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for the cause and I would recommend having a look at [How to use Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) as a possible solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer I did not want to use a swing timer for this project, I am practicing using recursion.

Comment: Well, then you need to stop blocking the EDT, which is what the Swing `Timer` affords you. Consider a `SwingWorker` instead. Beware, `Thread.sleep` only guarantees a minimum delay; Swing is NOT thread safe, so you need to make sure you only update the UI from within the context of the EDT and you're running the risk of a `StackOverFlowException`

Comment: `I am practicing using recursion.` - this is not a practical usage of recursion. There is definitely no need to keep creating components and adding them to the frame.

Comment: @camickr good point, I should make a separate method which adds on to seconds and updates the Label.

Comment: Recursion is not just invoking the same method from the same method, this is just a loop. Recursion is when you actually do some processing like listing the files in a directory. So you pass a parameter to a `getFiles()` method. The method then lists the files. When if finds a directory it then invoke `getFiles(...)` again with the new directory. This repeats until all the files are listed and the method terminates itself.

Comment: @camickr OK, thank you for clarifying. I thought that this program _was_ using recursion, but you're right. I will edit my post to fix that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main window does not appear, because you called infinite recursion inside constructor. GUITimer will not be created and this lock main thread.

You need use multithreading for this aim. Main thread for drawing time, second thread increment and put value to label

For example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUITimer extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int seconds = 0;
    private Thread timerThread;
    private JLabel timeDisplay;

    public GUITimer()
    {
        initGUI();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void initGUI()
    {
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Timer");
        Font titleFont = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 32);
        title.setFont(titleFont);
        title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        title.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        title.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        title.setOpaque(true);
        add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        timeDisplay = new JLabel(Integer.toString(seconds));//this label shows seconds
        add(timeDisplay, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void start()
    {
        seconds = 0;
        timerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    timeDisplay.setText(Integer.toString(seconds++));
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e) {}
                }
            }
        });
        timerThread.start();
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        timerThread.interrupt();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            GUITimer timer = new GUITimer();
            timer.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @theProgrammer101, you could look at above

Comment: Since Swing is NOT thread safe, you should not be updating the UI from your `Thread`. A safer alternative might be to use a `SwingWorker` - Oh, and your `stop` method isn't actually going to do anything

Answer (score 4):

The core issue is, you're blocking the UI by continuously calling `initGUI`, which will eventually fail with a `StackOverFlowException`, as the method calls never end

The preference would be to use a Swing `Timer`, but since you've stated you don't want to do that, a better solution would be to use a `SwingWorker`, the reason for this - Swing is NOT thread safe and `SwingWorker` provides a convenient mechanism for allowing us to update the UI safely.

Because both Swing `Timer` and `Thead.sleep` only guarantee a minimum delay, they are not a reliable means for measuring the passage of time, it would be better to make use of Java 8's Date/Time API instead

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label = new JLabel("00:00:00");
        private TimeWorker timeWorker;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(label, gbc);

            JButton button = new JButton("Start");
            add(button, gbc);

            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (timeWorker == null) {
                        timeWorker = new TimeWorker(label);
                        timeWorker.execute();
                        button.setText("Stop");
                    } else {
                        timeWorker.cancel(true);
                        timeWorker = null;
                        button.setText("Start");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public class TimeWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Duration> {

        private JLabel label;

        public TimeWorker(JLabel label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.now();
            Duration totalDuration = Duration.ZERO;
            while (!isCancelled()) {
                LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
                Duration tickDuration = Duration.between(startTime, now);
                publish(tickDuration);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Duration> chunks) {
            Duration duration = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
            String text = format(duration);
            label.setText(text);
        }

        public String format(Duration duration) {
            long hours = duration.toHours();
            duration = duration.minusHours(hours);
            long minutes = duration.toMinutes();
            duration = duration.minusMinutes(minutes);
            long millis = duration.toMillis();
            long seconds = (long)(millis / 1000.0);

            return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
        }
    }
}
```